# How to make customAppender to behave asynchronous like ConsoleAppender

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, logging, log4j

//@Component
public class MyAppender extends AppenderSkeleton {

```
@Override
protected void append(LoggingEvent event) {
System.out.println("Peform Sending sns task here ........");

try {
    //Send to Sns or any other source
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println("done sleeping");    
}

static{
    System.out.println("Loading MyAppender Class");
}

@Override
public void close() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public boolean requiresLayout() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
```

}//EOF MyAppender

public class LoggingFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

```
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        final FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {


        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);


        System.out.println("Logging is Started From Filters >>>>>>>>>>>");

            logger.debug("This is my test Log Msg 1");
            logger.debug("This is my test Log Msg 2");
            logger.debug("This is my test Log Msg 3");
            logger.debug("This is my test Log Msg 4");
            logger.debug("This is my test Log Msg 5");

        System.out.println("Logging is Completed in Filters >>>>>>>>>>>");
```

}
}

Expecting output:
Logging is Started From Filters
Logging is completed From Filters

rest things done externally but my flow is sequential

Comment: Instead on writing your requirements in comments , please edit your question and write it there. Your code is unreadable in comments

Comment: What's the question? What's your logging configuration?

Comment: Done with Editing I am expecting from the filters that as logger is async process filters should not wait till all the logging statements are executed it should continue and in MyAppender class i.e custom appender i should be able to perform some other task. i.e my requirement is that filter & Appender should work independently